Extract array with pixel values from magick image
I simply try to retrieve and change the array with pixel values after reading images via image_read(). However, I don't know how to access the data.
library(magick)
f = system.file("images", "sample-color.png", package="EBImage")
t = image_read(f)
>t
# A tibble: 1 × 7
  format width height colorspace matte filesize density
  <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>      <lgl>    <int> <chr>  
1 PNG      768    512 sRGB       FALSE   556865 72x72 

What I'd like to do is something like (lets pretend that t is a 3D array):
t[1:10,1:10,1] = 0 # set pixel values to '0' for the top left 10x10 square

or
arr = t[1:10,1:10,1] # retrieve pixel values from the top left 10x10 square

There is probably a simple solution to this problem but I just can't get my head around this right now.

PLease note, {magick} returns bitmap as a 3 dim matrix where 1st dim is number of layer.
library(magick)
f = system.file("images", "sample-color.png", package="EBImage")
i = image_read(f)

d <- i[[1]] # or use d <- image_data(i)
d[, 1:40, 1:40] <- as.raw(c(0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff))
image_read(d)


BTW, there is {imager} package which might be useful.
Created on 2024-10-30 with reprex v2.1.0
